# Why does CSS width: calc(inherit) do something different than width: inherit?

Tags: html, css, width

I am a middle school student experimenting around with CSS and HTML, and I noticed that width: calc(inherit) does something different than width: inherit.

The following snippet is what width: inherit; does.

```css
.header {
 background-color: #77a4ed;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: fit-content;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 20px;
}

.header > div {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 border-right: solid 2px black;
 border-left: solid 2px black;
 border-top: solid 2px black;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: inherit;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.header > div:last-of-type {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 border-right: solid 2px black;
 border-left: solid 2px black;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: fit-content;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border-bottom: solid 2px black;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='header'>
&nbsp;
<div>
test
</div>
<div>
test..........................................................
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This snippet is what width: calc(inherit); does.

```css
.header {
 background-color: #77a4ed;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: fit-content;
 border-top-left-radius: 50px;
 border-top-right-radius: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 height: 20px;
}

.header > div {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 border-right: solid 2px black;
 border-left: solid 2px black;
 border-top: solid 2px black;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: calc(inherit);
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.header > div:last-of-type {
 background-color: whitesmoke;
 border-right: solid 2px black;
 border-left: solid 2px black;
 min-width: 200px;
 width: fit-content;
 margin: auto;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border-bottom: solid 2px black;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='header'>
    &nbsp;
    <div>
    test
    </div>
    <div>
    test..........................................................
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I don't understand why they would give different results. Could someone explain?

Comment: `calc(inherit)` is simply invalid

Comment: calc() is a value, not a rule that might inherit a value ... but var()  can be used inside ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the console.log you will see that calc doesn't work with inherit.

```css
#a1{
width:inherit;
}

#a2{
width: calc (inherit);
}
```

```html
<div id='a1'>xxx</div>
<div id='a2'>xxx</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

calc() is suppose to calculate using a mathematical expression like -, +, *, or /
example

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

you don't have any expression so it's probably not valid but maybe if you make the .header width have an expression then use the inherit that may work

```
.header{
    width: cal(100% - 100px);
}
.header{
    width: inherit;
}
```

that might work but not sure also I don't know if 100% - 100px is the exact width youre looking for

Answer (score -1):

Just use `width: 100%` and it will take up the whole width of the parent element.